Generalizations of quadratic programs in optimization
I have learned about binary constrained optimization problems before, where we want to optimise the expression x^tQx, where x is some component-wise n-dimensional binary vector, and Q is a n x n matrix.
Now I was wondering if there is an equivalent notion in higher dimension, e.g., an optimization of x^tQx^2, where Q is no longer a n x n matrix, but a n x n x n tensor.
This is of interest since such a formulation might help formulate the capset problem as optimization problem, which would be quite interesting. It would be interesting to know whether or not anyone has seen such a tensor optimisation before.
